# Updating Data to db in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem while updating data to the database in laravel.  Normally the data gets inserted to the database with store function(POST request).  But the update POST request doesn't make a update to the database.  And my code is

routes.php

```
Route::resource('Customer','CustomerDetailController');
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
```

Model
CustomerDetail.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CustomerDetail extends Model
{
//

public $table = "customer_details";
protected $fillable = [
'Name', 'Contact_Number','Address','NoOfCans','Price'
];
}
```

Controller
CustomerDetailController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\CustomerDetail;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class CustomerDetailController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
    $Customers=CustomerDetail::all();
    if($Customers){

    $response = [
        'msg' => 'Customer Found',
        'Customer' => $Customers
    ];
    return response()->json($response, 201);
  }
  else {
    $response=[
      'msg'=>'No Customer Found',
    ];
    return response()->json($response, 404);
  }
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //

    $this->validate($request, [
        'Name' => 'required',
        'Contact_Number' => 'required',
        'Address' => 'required',
        'NoOfCans' => 'required',
        'Price' => 'required',
    ]);

    $Name = $request->input('Name');
    $Contact_Number = $request->input('Contact_Number');
    $Address = $request->input('Address');
    $NoOfCans = $request->input('NoOfCans');
    $Price = $request->input('Price');

    $CustomerDetail = new CustomerDetail([
        'Name' => $Name,
        'Contact_Number' => $Contact_Number,
        'Address' => $Address,
        'NoOfCans' => $NoOfCans,
        'Price' => $Price
    ]);
    if ($CustomerDetail->save()) {

        $response = [
            'msg' => 'Customer Created',
            'Customer' => $CustomerDetail
        ];
        return response()->json($response, 201);
    }
    $response = [
        'msg' => 'An Error Occured',
    ];
    return response()->json($response, 502);


}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //

    $Customer=CustomerDetail::find($id);
    if($Customer){

    $response = [
        'msg' => 'Customer Found',
        'Customer' => $Customer
    ];
    return response()->json($response, 201);
  }
  else {
    $response=[
      'msg'=>'Customer Not Found',
    ];
    return response()->json($response, 404);
  }


}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    $this->validate($request, [
        'Name' => 'required',
        'Contact_Number' => 'required',
        'Address' => 'required',
        'NoOfCans' => 'required',
        'Price' => 'required',
    ]);


    $CustomerUpdate = CustomerDetail::find($id);
    $CustomerUpdate->Name = $request->input('Name');
    $CustomerUpdate->Contact_Number = $request->input('Contact_Number');
    $CustomerUpdate->Address = $request->input('Address');
    $CustomerUpdate->NoOfCans = $request->input('NoOfCans');
    $CustomerUpdate->Price = $request->input('Price');

    if ($CustomerUpdate->save()) {

        $response = [
            'msg' => 'Customer Updated',
            'Customer' => $CustomerUpdate
        ];
        return response()->json($response, 201);
    }
    $response = [
        'msg' => 'An Error Occured',
    ];
    return response()->json($response, 502);

}

}
```

And the data gets inserted when i make a post request for store as

```
{
"Name":"MRK",
"Contact_Number":"1234567890",
"Address":"newyork",
"NoOfCans":"3",
"Price":"20"
}
```

with Output

```
{
 "msg": "Customer Created",
 "Customer": {
 "Name": "MRK",
 "Contact_Number": "1234567890",
 "Address": "newyork",
 "NoOfCans": "3",
 "Price": "20",
 "updated_at": "2016-11-20 17:17:55",
 "created_at": "2016-11-20 17:17:55",
 "id": 4
}
}
```

But when I try to Update the same data with PUT or PATCH request

Input

```
{
    "Name":"MRK",
    "Contact_Number":"9876543210",
    "Address":"Chennai",
    "NoOfCans":"2",
    "Price":"20"
}
```

I get the JSON Response as Updated but I don't see the values got Updated in the database

```
{
  "msg": "Customer Updated",
  "Customer": {
    "ID": 4,
    "created_at": "2016-11-20 17:17:55",
    "updated_at": "2016-11-20 17:20:44",
    "Name": "MRK",
    "Contact_Number": "9876543210",
    "Address": "Chennai",
    "NoOfCans": "2",
    "Price": "20"
  }
}
```

The database contains the values which are originally inserted at first.  No updated values are inserted into the database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVy4E.png)

Update code

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
    //
    $this->validate($request, [
        'Name' => 'required',
        'Contact_Number' => 'required',
        'Address' => 'required',
        'NoOfCans' => 'required',
        'Price' => 'required',
    ]);


    $CustomerUpdate = CustomerDetail::find($id);
    $CustomerUpdate->Name = $request->input('Name');
    $CustomerUpdate->Contact_Number = $request->input('Contact_Number');
    $CustomerUpdate->Address = $request->input('Address');
    $CustomerUpdate->NoOfCans = $request->input('NoOfCans');
    $CustomerUpdate->Price = $request->input('Price');

    if ($CustomerUpdate->save()) {

        $response = [
            'msg' => 'Customer Updated',
            'Customer' => $CustomerUpdate
        ];
        return response()->json($response, 201);
    }
    $response = [
        'msg' => 'An Error Occured',
    ];
    return response()->json($response, 502);

}
```

Comment: can you post the update method from `CustomerDetailController`

Comment: Yes using the update method from CustomerDetailController i tried but not working

Comment: I am new to laravel bro can you please elaborate

Comment: In the `CustomerDetailController` you should have an `update` function. We need to see that code.

Comment: I have edited my question with update code

Comment: im not sure, never tried it, but try to change ->save() to ->update() since im guessing that save() will save a new row instead.

Comment: The same problem exists after changing ->save() to ->update()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the model.  I have not mentioned the primary key in my model so the database is not updated

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CustomerDetail extends Model
{
//

public $table = "customer_details";
Protected $primaryKey = "ID";
protected $fillable = [
'Name', 'Contact_Number','Address','NoOfCans','Price'
];
}
```